# How to format dash datatable cell using HTML code in cell string?

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

### MWE

Suppose one has:

```py
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

data = OrderedDict(
    [
        ("Name", ["a", "b", "c"]),
        ("Region", [ "Toronto", "<b> First </b>", '<b style="display:inline">Second</b>',]),
    ]
)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Which outputs:
[image]

(Note at the second column, the third and fourth row are HTML formatted, but this is not picked up by Dash).

### Question

How can one ensure the html content of these cell content strings, is parsed by Dash in the table?

### Note

The [examples](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/conditional-formatting) given in the Dash documentation for conditional formatting write separate, non-pythonic/elaborate/api-like code to format specific cells. However, for the intended use case, it would be less complicated, if I can store the conditional data in the string, at the time of creating the cell content, instead of creating extra data tables per cell with the relevant formatting of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

An unsafe solution has been found with:

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
from typeguard import typechecked

data = OrderedDict(
    [
        ("Name", ["a", "b", "c", "d"]),
        ("Region", [
            "Toronto",
            '<b> First </b>',
            '<u>Second</u>',
            "f"
        ]),
    ]
)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Row 1', 'value': '1'},
            {'label': 'Row 2', 'value': '2'}
        ],
        value=None
    ),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(
        id='table',
        children=[
            dcc.Markdown(
                dangerously_allow_html=True,
                children=df.to_html(escape=False)
            )
        ]
    )
])


@app.callback(
    Output('table', 'children'),
    [Input('dropdown', 'value')]
)
def update_table(value):
    if value == '1':
        updated_df = df.copy()
        updated_df.iloc[1, :] = updated_df.iloc[1, :].apply(lambda x: f'<b>{x}</b>')
        return dcc.Markdown(
            dangerously_allow_html=True,
            children=updated_df.to_html(escape=False)
        )
    elif value == '2':
        updated_df = df.copy()
        updated_df.iloc[2, :] = updated_df.iloc[2, :].apply(lambda x: f'<b>{x}</b>')
        return dcc.Markdown(
            dangerously_allow_html=True,
            children=updated_df.to_html(escape=False)
        )
    else:
        return dcc.Markdown(
            dangerously_allow_html=True,
            children=df.to_html(escape=False)
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Which applies the bold settings through parsing the HTML code inside the cell (unsafe), and allows switches the cell formatting using a dropdown box.